# using simple_html_dom with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm doing the Parser of a page with the 'simple_html_dom' library however not got success to parse an html whose content is obtained through ajax. is there any way around this?

PHP Code:

```
<?php
require_once '../library/Simple_HTML_DOM/simple_html_dom.php';

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.playnow3dgames.com/genre.php?id=sports');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){
echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Only prints the images on the edges and top (html native) and Is not parsed the center images (using ajax).

Comment: is this page http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&order=date ?

Comment: You mean you don’t get content that is only added to the page via JavaScript? Well of course not, because `file_get_contents` doesn’t “execute” JavaScript. You need something that emulates a browser for that (research keyword: `headless browser`)

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to phamtomjs, hope it works in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
<?php
require_once '../library/Simple_HTML_DOM/simple_html_dom.php';

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&order=date');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){
    echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
?>
```

**=== UPDATE ====**

actualy, this a iframe, it is not ajax.
in center of http://www.playnow3dgames.com/genre.php?id=sports is frame: http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&order=date

you can see struct of url:

```
http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=sports&order=date
```

at here:  `genre=sports`

this is real url: `http://www.playnow3dgames.com/genre.php?id=sports`

you will see match of `id=sports` with `genre=sports`

to get for every pages, you only need change `genre=genre_name`. for example:

```
http://www.playnow3dgames.com/genre.php?id=strategy
```

the main frame will be:

```
www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=strategy&order=date
```

if you want to get page 1,2,3..., you need add `page=page_number`. for example: get page 2 of

```
http://www.playnow3dgames.com/genre.php?id=strategy
```

url will be:

```
http://www.playnow3dgames.com/listing.php?genre=strategy&page=2&order=date
```

Comment: Thanks for answer ,@MrJerry, 1st where is this listing.php? 2nd works but works for every site with use ajax?

Comment: see my update for get every pages